# How to fix 'undefined index' when posting a variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am posting some variables to a php file. The variables are coming from a form. So, when I put the variables in the form, they are posted to the php file. However, when I want to actually use the variables, they come as an undefined index. I have to use json_encode and retrieve the variables using the post call back function. But I want the variables to work when using the get function/method. I am a beginner so please go easy on me.

I have tried to put the post function before the get get function.
I have tried to use json_decode
I have tried to using $_REQUEST instead of $_POST
If json_encode is JUST used to echo the $_POST variable, then it will show in the call back 'success' function. But I want the $_POST variables to be used generously through out the code and show when the get function is used.
Looking through other peoples answers, I see that apparently the index for the $_POST is undefined/null. But my code sends the form to the PHP, so it shouldn't be null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Combining HTML, JS & PHP</h1>

<form id="IPLAnalyisForm" method="post">
     <div>
        <select name="opponent">
        <option name = "Sunrisers Hyderabad" value="Sunrisers Hyderabad">Sunrisers Hyderabad</option>
        <option name = "Royal Challengers Bangalore" value="Royal Challengers Bangalore">Royal Challengers Bangalore</option>
        <option name = "Kolkata Knight Riders" value="Kolkata Knight Riders">Kolkata Knight Riders</option>
        <option name = "Delhi Daredevils" value="Delhi Daredevils">Delhi Daredevils</option>
        <option name = "Kings XI Punjab" value="Kings XI Punjab">Kings XI Punjab</option>
        <option name = "Rajasthan Royals" value="Rajasthan Royals">Rajasthan Royals</option>
    </select>

        <input onclick="getData()" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"     value="submit parameters"/>
    </div>
 </form>
 <button onclick="getData()">Submit query</button>

 <div id = "result"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 </script>
 </body>
 <script src="IPL.js"></script>
 </html>
```

JavaScript (with some Jquery)
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IPLAnalyisForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'IPL.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function()
        {
            // var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
            // alert(jsonData);
        }
    });
});
});

function getData() {
    obj = {"table": "batting", "limit": 5};
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "IPL.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP CODE

```
  $opponent =  $_POST['opponent'];
  echo $opponent;
```

Comment: To all that have answered. Thank you soooo much. I really appreciate the friendliness of your answers. Keep it up. I will try your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` index for the following `XMLHttpRequest`

```
function getData() {
    obj = {"table": "batting", "limit": 5};
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "IPL.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In your `IPL.php` file, you are trying to access `opponent` index of `$_POST` but you didn't set parameter `opponent` when you requested from `getData()`.

So, you should do a [**POST**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST) request with `opponent` parameter by `XMLHttpRequest` or check in PHP side by `isset` like

```
$opponent = isset($_POST['opponent']) ? $_POST['opponent'] : null;
echo $opponent;
```